# Is the sum of two prime ideals a prime ideal?

Tags: ring-theory

Is the sum of two prime ideals (of a ring) again a prime ideal?

Please can someone give me a hint? I know that the intersection of two prime ideals is again a prime ideal iff one is contained in the other, but I'm not sure about the sum.

Comment: Prime ideals are neither closed under sums, nor under intersection. Look at prime ideals in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Are you sure about the intersection? Take the two prime ideals $2 \mathbb{Z}$ and $3 \mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: $2\mathbb{Z}\cap 3\mathbb{Z}=6\mathbb{Z}$ which is not a prime ideal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Th answer is no, consider the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ and the prime ideals $(2)$ and $(5)$. Since two and five are relative primes then every number can be written as a linear combination over $\mathbb{Z}$ of 2 and 5. To see this. note that if if $k$ is any interger, since we know that
$$5-(2)2=1$$
by multiplying by $k$ we obtain the expression
$$k5-(2k)2=k$$
which is a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of $k$ in therms of $2$ and $5$. Note that $k5\in(5)$ and $-2k(2)=-4k\in(2)$. This means that $(2)+(5)=\mathbb{Z}$, which is not a prime ideal.

Note that the sum of ideals is an ideal when one is contained in the other. This is not possible in $\mathbb{Z}$ with the exemption when of the ideals is the prime ideal $(0)$, but other rings can give more interesting examples. Have a look at polynomials rings for example.

Comment: how is that if two  and 5 are relatively prime yhen every ... of 2 and 5.

Comment: two integers are relative prime iff you can express the number 1 as a linear combination of the two numbers, it follows from euclid's algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Another example where the sum $P_1+P_2$ of prime ideals is a proper ideal, but not prime:

Take $P_1=(x^2+y), P_2=(x^4+y)\in\Bbb Q[x,y]$. Both these ideals are prime since, $\Bbb Q[x,y]/(x^2+y)\cong\Bbb Q[x]$ and $\Bbb Q[x,y]/(x^4+y)\cong\Bbb Q[x]$.

We have $x^2(x^2-1)\in P_1+P_2$, but neither factor is. To see this, suppose $$x^2=f(x,y)(x^4+y)+g(x,y)(x^2+y)$$ Then evaluate $y$ at $-x^2$. This is a homomorphsm $\Bbb Q[x,y]\rightarrow \Bbb Q[x]$, and gives $$x^2=f(x,-x^2)(x^4-x^2)\\\Rightarrow 1=f(x,-x^2)(x^2-1)$$ This is impossible, since the only units in $k[x]$ lies in $k^\times$.

We may use the same trick for $x^2-1$. $$x^2-1=f(x,-x^2)(x^4-x^2)\\\Rightarrow 1=f(x,-x^2)x^2$$ I've used the fact that a monic polynomial is never a zero-divisor.

Thus the ideal $P_1+P_2$ is not prime, and it is also proper, since $P_1+P_2\subseteq (x,y)$.

Answer (score -6):

I think (correct me if I'm wrong) that if you are not so restrictive in your definition of prime ideals (allowing 1 to belong to a prime ideal) the answer is positive.

For instance, let $p_{1}$ and $p_{2}$ be two prime ideals of $R$, and take the natural projection map $\pi: R \longrightarrow R/p_{1}$, then $\pi(p_{2})$ is a prime ideal because $\pi$ is a surjective map and $p_{2}$ is a prime ideal. But then, $\pi^{-1}(\pi(p_{2}))$ is a prime ideal in R, and $\pi^{-1}(\pi(p_{2}))=p_{1}+p_{2}$.

Comment: 1. The ideal $(1)$ is not prime. 2. In $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ the ideals $(y)$ and $(x^2+y^2-1)$ are prime but their sum is not. Images don't preserve primeness. That is,  $\pi(p_2)$ is not necessarily prime.

Comment: I started my answer by saying that "if one is not so restrictive in the definition of the prime ideals (allowing 1 to belong to a prime ideal)", I'm not saying every prime ideal must have a 1, but rather that I'm allowing (1) to also be a prime ideal

Comment: Images do preserve primeness if the map is surjective

Comment: No. The unit ideal is not prime. If you want a different definition then use a different word. And quotient images of primes are not necessarily prime as shown by the example in my comment.

Comment: You may want to read the definition of a prime ideal from Wolfram http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeIdeal.html where he says that whether it is proper or not depends on the author

Comment: Only for prime ideas that contain the kernel.

Comment: We are being a little feisty today. If we consult Zariski and Samuel *Commutative Algebra*, Volume 1, we see on p. 149, following the definition of prime ideal of a (commutative) ring $R$, the remark : "In particular, $R$ itself is always prime." If I recall, it was later made convention that prime ideals be proper, much as $1$ is no longer considered a prime (in order to preserve uniqueness of prime factorization).